# Prove that there does not exist a $n$-regular polygon $(n\ge 4)$, such that its sides and diagonals are all integers.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, polygons, geometric-construction, geometry-of-numbers

Prove that there does not exist a $n$-regular polygon $(n≥4)$, such that its sides and diagonals are all integers. Maybe a famous problem, but I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: What about a regular hexagon with unit sides? All its diagonal would be of length 2.

Comment: A regular hexagon has two different kinds of diagonals. If the side length is 1, the diagonals passing through the center have length 2, but the diagonals that connect a vertex with a non-opposite, non-adjacent vertex don't have integer length.

Comment: The non-"diameter" diagonals aren't, though.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for clarifying guys

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0ahUKEwj6u56hqObLAhWBqSwKHSHDAHQQFghEMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhrcak.srce.hr%2Ffile%2F2836&usg=AFQjCNFq2QsTAq6VI44tInyqjXeAv-jlMw&cad=rja) helps

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the lengths of the sides and the diagonals of $n$-regular polygon $A_1A_2\cdots A_n$ with side lenghths $a$ are all integers.

Since 
$$\overline{A_iA_{i+2}}=\frac{a\sin\left(\frac{360}{n}\right)^\circ}{\sin\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)^\circ}=2a\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)^\circ$$

is an integer, we have that $\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)^\circ$ is rational.

By (the extension of) [Niven's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem), we have 
$$\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)^\circ=0,\quad \pm\frac 12,\quad \pm 1$$
which contradicts that $n\ge 4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\zeta\in\Bbb C$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity. The existence of such a polygon would imply that for some $r>0$ the numbers $r\left|\zeta^k-1\right|$ are integer for all $k\in\Bbb Z$.
In particular, $$\tag1q:=\left|\zeta+1\right|=\frac{r\left|\zeta^2-1\right|}{r\left|\zeta^1-1\right|}\in\Bbb Q$$
so that $q^2=(\zeta+1)(\overline\zeta+1)$ and $\zeta,\overline\zeta$ are the roots of the quadratic polynomial
$$\tag2X^2- (q^2-2)X+1\in\Bbb Q[X].$$
Hence  $\phi(n)=[\Bbb Q[\zeta]:\Bbb Q]\le 2$ and from this we conclude that $n$ is not divisible by any prime $p>3$ (which would make $\phi(n)\ge p-1>2$), nor divisible by $3^2$ (which would make $\phi(n)\ge 6$), nor divisible by $2^3$ (which would make $\phi(n)\ge 4$), nor divisible by $2^23$ (which would make $\phi(n)\ge 4$). Thus we are left only with $n=1,2,3,4,6$.
For $n=6$, the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is $X^2-X+1$ so that by comparison with $(2)$ we have $q^2=3$, which is absurd.
For $n=4$, the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is $X^2+1$ so that by comparison with $(2)$ we have $q^2=2$, which is again absurd. We conclude $n\le 3$.

*Remark:*
We used only $(1)$, i.e., only that the side lengths $A_iA_{i+1}$ and the *shortest* diagonals $A_iA_{i+2}$ are integral.